# Issue in JMeter -Specify Thread lifetime-

Tags: jmeter

I'm using JMeter (5.4.3).

I noticed that the Duration of Thread group isn't working.

And here's an example of what I've tried.
Number of threads: 300
I've Checked Specify Thread lifetime checkbox .. Duration : 5
(So it supposed to be ended in 5 seconds)

The result is that the test ended in 33 seconds ..

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter "asks" threads to stop when the lifetime ends.

If response time is higher than the test duration it might be the case that JMeter will wait for the response prior to finishing the thread.

If you need to stop the test in 5 seconds make sure to limit the JMeter's timeout to be 5 seconds maximum.

If you're using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers - the setting lives under "Advanced" tab

[image]

If you have multiple HTTP Request samplers - it's a good idea to use [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) so you could define the timeout in one place.

Other JMeter Configuration Elements and/or Samplers also have timeout settings.

If there are no timeouts - there is [stoptest](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/bin/stoptest.cmd) script which could be used for terminating the running test (be aware that it will be "force" termination and may result in false negative results)

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer